# Adding a text link to a hyperlink on a email

Tags: java, email, hyperlink, formatting

I am working on a notification message in Java that sends a message and a hyperlink. Now the hyperlink is way too long depending and was asked to make it like a link text similar to how its done on html and on hotmail.

```
<a href="http://www.hello_world.com/">Hello world</a>
```

Now the email i am sending can't be sent as a html page just text. Is there a way of making this happen on text to where when the user just see's the word "here" or something and it goes to the hyperlink?

Comment: Does the notification send the email? Do you want to display a text instead of a link? How is the email sent and then viewed?

The question is a bit to ambiguous as of now. Can you just not display something to the user and include the link in the email body itself?

Comment: The notification does send the email. And yes i do want to display a text instead of a link. the email is being sent as a smtp server but can be viewed on anything I believe as its all plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if the email is not html, there is not a way to include hyperlinks in an only text email. Just send the url and most email clients will construct a clickable hyperlink out of it.

Comment: I do that , and yes most email clients do construct the hyperlink I am just wondering if there is any text i can send that makes the email clients construct the hyperlink to display just the link text.

Comment: I know what you meant. My answer is that there isn't a way.